# Mysql query for full text search with an OR condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, match-against

I have a dropdown list where it contains only two options `And` and `Or`. These two options when selected will run a query however depending on the selection. When `And` is selected, a change in the query will be made. My query looks like this,

```
$sql = 
            "SELECT distinct n.node_id, n.path, 
               n.title_tag as node_name, 
               n2.title_tag as tree_name,
               MATCH (n.title_tag) AGAINST ('%s') as score
            FROM nodes n 
               join trees t on (n.tree_id=t.tree_id and t.status='A' and t.workspace_id=%d)
               join nodes n2 on (n2.node_id = t.tree_id)
               left join node_links nl1 on (n.node_id=nl1.from_node_id and nl1.to_node_id='%s')
               left join node_links nl2 on (n.node_id=nl2.to_node_id and nl2.from_node_id='%s')
            WHERE n.node_id!='%s' and nl1.node_link_id is null and nl2.node_link_id is null
            HAVING score > 0
            ORDER BY score DESC";
```

Notice the `MATCH AGAINST` part, that is where I would like to add my `And` and `Or` conditions. How would I do it if when selecting the `And` condition the query will match the `node_name` using the `AND` logic and when selecting the `Or` condition the query will match the `node_name` using the `OR` logic. Any help will do. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html ?

Comment: @BillKarwin, I can honestly swear I have missed to read the link you gave. I'll try this one and will see if this works. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @BillKarwin, how would I upvote you to give you credit for the tip? Can you post your answer?

Comment: Give the upvote to @diEcho, for taking the time to show a more complete example.  The important thing is to give you good help, and I'm not hurting for points!  :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin another quick question, how would I determine if the query worked? I tried to echo the queries being used for `And` and `Or` and it resulted to the same results. Did I miss something wrong?

Comment: Query a test table you populate with test data specifically containing one word, the other word, or both words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU the question you want to add a condition based on the selection of a choice (stored in `$condition` ) from front end, if so then please give a try to below code: (not tested)

```
switch($condition) {
                case "AND" : $searchNode = "+$searchTerm"; break;
                case "OR"  : 
                default    :
                             $searchNode = "$searchTerm"; break;
}

$final_search = "$searchTitle $searchNode";

$sql = "SELECT distinct n.node_id, n.path, 
                   n.title_tag as node_name, 
                   n2.title_tag as tree_name,
                   MATCH (n.title_tag,n.node_name) 
                   AGAINST ($final_search IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score ..." ;
```

[`Reference`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html)